# how to have different description meta tags for each site with master.html

Tags: html, asp.net

I am following the advice on

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/03/tipjar-title-tags-and-master-pages.aspx/

to get different title tags for each page on my website. I use

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="titleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
```

...

in my master.html and

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="titleContent" runat="server">
My site
</asp:Content>
```

for all my pages. My question is how can I also have different description tags for each page?

Comment: Do exactly the same thing?

Comment: This is an ASP question, so please add the ASP tag.

Comment: @SLaks, can you give an example? The title tag and the meta tag don't work in the same way, so its not clear to me how to do it...

Comment: @carl: Just put the entire tag in the placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SLaks said in the comments, you basically just do the same thing for the meta tags.

Master page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="metaContent" runat="server" />
```

Content page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="metaContent" runat="server">
    <meta name="description" content="This page is about product X">
    <meta name="keywords" content="x,product,fancy,nice,highquality">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This way is how to make different meta tags for pages statically. Would be better if you also would like to show how it will be dynamically.

Comment: HtmlMeta hm = new HtmlMeta(); hm.Name = "description"; hm.Content = "here is the description of page"; this.Header.Controls.Add(hm); like this

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `<title></title>` tag in your MasterPage like this:

```
<title> <%: Page.Title %> </title>
```

Then, you should have your, let's say, Default.ASPX page like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Add Your Title Right Here, Please" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="YOUR_MASTER_PAGE.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

This example takes into consideration the fact that the tutorial talks on ASP.NET MVC.

I'd say you should use Visual Studio (2015) for this, just in case you aren't using it.

You can download the VS 2015 [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx). The community version is free.

Comment: Please, someone close this post. The answer marked as "right" is not even "right". That way you adding a meta tag to the body tag what's wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198726/how-to-add-meta-tag-to-asp-net-content-page This is the answer! The post is duplicated!!!

Comment: How is my answer wrong? It does exactly what was asked for, and the answer was accepted by the user that asked the question. Your answer appears to be wrong, because it doesn't address anything to do with meta tags. The post you linked to in your comment is an alternative way of going about this, but it is certainly not the only way.

Comment: I only considered his snippet which only refers to <title></title>. And as long as my answer is incorrect for being incomplete,  yours should be marked as well, because you don't explain the need of adding new contentPLaceholder ASP tags to the file. The way you put on your answer just let people thing that you can add <meta> tags to the body of your HTML document.

Comment: Your answer is not correct because it doesn't explain what needs to be done differently in order to add a description. And I think it's clear enough from my example where the meta tags belong.

Comment: Okay, @mason! I'm sorry!!! I was just mad, because someone downvoted my answer without explaining why. This is just not productive. I can't learn from that. I can't learn from someone saying "It's wring!" without saying why. Stack Overflow should be a community to  construct knowledge, not just to give away badges or points.

Comment: In my mind, your answer is so clearly wrong that an explanation is hardly necessary. And why did you revert my edit on your post? You're using code snippets incorrectly, you should use code blocks when you have any sort of server side markup.

Comment: I didn't revert your edition. I just corrected the "Should" word that I misspelled. Also, look at my reputation, dude! Of course I need some explanation, don't you think?

Comment: Look at what you answered, and look at the question that was asked. The question is asking how to add a description tags, and he demonstrated that he was able to use content place holders with the title tag. You then answered how to add a page title. So if someone had asked "How do I add a page title in ASP.NET" then your answer would be good. But you answered *the wrong thing* and should therefore delete your answer