# How to use meta tags on pages in asp.net webpages

Tags: asp.net, razor, meta-tags, asp.net-webpages

How to use meta tags on single pages using asp.net webpages. I'm currently using a layout master page with default meta tags which  works across several pages, but I can't seem to find a way to override the meta tags for sub pages of the master file.

On the sub pages I've the following but it does work.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/siteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Meta Page";
    Page.MetaKeywords = "keyword1, keyword2, keyword3";
}
```

Can anyone please assist or point me in the right direction, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Use in your layout something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.Keywords">
```

And then in your controller, layout or view, you have to set `ViewBag.Title` and `ViewBag.Keywords`. Here is an example of how to set it in a view that uses layout above.

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_YourLayout.cshtml";
   ViewBag.Title = "My Page Title";
   ViewBag.Keywords = "keyword1, keyword2";
}
```

The `ViewBag` property enables you to dynamically share values from the controller to the view. Internally `ViewBag` properties are stored as name/value pairs in the `ViewData` that is like a dictionary where you can store random stuff that you want to use in your view.

Comment: Hi @Rawson I'm getting a run-time error whenever I use the viewbag property on the pages as you explained. Will this work on Webpages or strictly MVC? I'm not sure if that is the reason for the error.

Comment: It is Razor syntax that is fully supported by ASP.NET MVC framework (it is not working in ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET Web Pages). I think that you are mixing Web Pages and MVC framework. Please, read this thread first: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6198826/5495799).